# AngularJS Component binding not updating the view on Callback

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-components

I have an Angular Component (v1.6.5) which incorporates the following simplified scenario in its controller:

```
var $ctrl = this;

$ctrl.$onInit = function () {
    $ctrl.dataItem = {
        showsOK: true
    }

    // works fine
    $ctrl.updateValues('showsOK2', true);

    // this definition is being passed to another component
    this.subComponentDefinition= {
        eventListeners: [
            {
                name: 'click',
                callback: function (event, map) {
                    // this is the callback where UpdateValues 
                    // does not update the view
                    $ctrl.updateValues('showsOK3', false);
                }
            }
        ],
    };
}

$ctrl.updateValues = function (prop, val) {
    $ctrl.dataItem[prop] = val;
};
```

I may be missing something in how the new version of Angular handles those binding. are binding being dropped at some point before the callback is called?

Comment: If the callback is invoked by an event from outside the AngularJS context, you can also use `$apply()` to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop).

Comment: yes. $apply works. but I did not need to do this with directives used with earlier versions of AngularJS. is this by design?

Comment: There are many scenarios where $apply is done automatically. If one uses ES6 promises, then those promises should be converted to AngularJS promises with `$q.when`. $apply will be automatically applied in that case. Problems occur when ES6 promises are not converted to $q promises. Also `$setViewValue` will automaatically invoke a digest cycle. I can't write an answer to your question because I don't know the source of the callback in your example.

Comment: hmmmm... interesting. in my case, the callback is being called from a google map, on a click event. any idea why this would act any different?

Comment: Callbacks from the Google Map API definitely need to be brought into the AngularJS framework either with $apply or $q.defer. That has not changed with versions of AngularJS.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).